# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.getApplicationStartup()

Tags: java, spring, jar, runtime, compatibility

We are getting the below error, when we are trying to migrate to the srping version.

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.getApplicationStartup()Lorg/springframework/core/metrics/ApplicationStartup;
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context.jar:5.2.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context.jar:5.2.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context.jar:5.2.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401) ~[spring-web.jar:5.2.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292) ~[spring-web.jar:5.2.20.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103) ~[spring-web.jar:5.2.20.RELEASE]
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.instantiatingListener(SecurePluginContextListener.java:357) ~[portal-kernel.jar:?]
at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SecurePluginContextListener.instantiatingListeners(SecurePluginContextListener.java:164) ~[portal-kernel.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.doInvokeDeploy(ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.java:74) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
at com.liferay.portal.deploy.hot.ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.invokeDeploy(ServletContextListenerHotDeployListener.java:37) ~[portal-impl.jar:?]
... 67 more

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                                        
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                    <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                    <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                    <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                    <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                    <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>                
                <configuration> 
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.11.jar</packagingExcludes>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>deploy_to_liferay</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                    <copy todir="${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}" >
                                    <fileset dir="./target">
                                        <include name="${project.artifactId}.war" />
                                    </fileset>
                                    </copy>                                 
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.8</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portletmvc4spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.portletmvc4spring.framework</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    
        
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.16.1-GA</version>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>


       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.32.Final</version>
       </dependency>
       
       
       <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
          <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.7</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>    
          
      <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
       <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
       <version>4.0.0.Final</version>
       
       
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdf-renderer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>  
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>  
        <version>2.0.24</version>  
        </dependency>  
          
        <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>  
        <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>  
        <version>2.0.24</version>  
        </dependency>  
        
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>  
            <artifactId>jempbox</artifactId>  
            <version>1.8.16</version>  
        </dependency>
          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmpbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
          
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>preflight</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
        </dependency>  
          
        <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>  
        <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>  
        <version>2.0.24</version>  
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dhorions</groupId>
        <artifactId>boxable</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency> 
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0-nightly</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0-nightly</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>util-bridges</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0-nightly</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax2-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-hc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mixing jars from different versions of a framework in this case Spring. Or using an incompatible library with this version. However you haven't shown your dependencies (please include your pom.xml or build.gradle).